# реализовать конечный автомат

Tags: javascript

как написать метод,который принимает символ и меняет текущее состояние

```js
var p0 = {
    name: 'p0',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
        'a': 'p1'
    }
};

var p1 = {
    name: 'p1',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
        'b': 'p2'
    }
};

var p2 = {
    name: 'p2',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
        'a': 'p3',
        'b': 'p4'
    }
};

var p3 = {
    name: 'p3',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
        'b': 'p5'
    }
};

var p4 ={
    name: 'p4',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
        'b': 'p4'
    }
};

var p5 = {
    name : 'p5',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
        'a': 'p3'
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="currentState">
<input type="button"  value="Запустить конечный автомат" onclick="start()">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кода много, но как он связан с указанными пунктами - непонятно

Comment: @Grunndy , на данном этапе не понимаю как реализовать проход по `listTransitions` при событии `go()`, и должны искаться соответствующие значения `currentState` = `firstState`, `enterLabel` = `addLabel`. Если такой переход найден, то в `currentState` заносится значение `secondState` из найденного перехода.

Comment: А есть схема конечного автомата который надо реализовать?

Comment: @grundy, добавила схему в вопрос

Comment: картинка с википедии точно относится к тому, что ты хочешь реализовать? На картинке все предельно просто есть 6 состояний от p0 До p5 в которые автомат переходит в зависимости от того какую из букв a/b ему передали. Судя по коду в вопросе ты что-то совсем другое хочешь сделать

Comment: ну отличие лишь  в том, что я сама задаю списки состояний и переходов.а потом лишь выбираю в каком состоянии начать,а в каком закончить. и задаю переходы.  а программа уже ищет соответствующее перовое значение и метку, и осуществляет переход.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76308/discussion-between-grundy-and-vita-run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечный автомат можно представить как карту состояний и переходов между ними и текущее состояние.

Карта состояния может быть обычным объектом, ключами в котором будут имена состояний, а значениями, сами состояния, например:

```
var states = {
    p0: {...},
    p1: {...},
    p2: {...},
    p3: {...},
    p4: {...},
    p5: {...},
};
```

инициализировать текущее состояние можно простым присвоением элемент из карты:

```
var current = states.p0;
```

Теперь функция перехода. Смысл ее очень прост:

1. Проверяем входной символ
2. если из текущего состояния нет перехода по этому символу - кидаем ошибку.

   ```
   if(!current.next[input]) throw new Error('invalid')
   ```
3. если есть - обновляем переменную current:

   ```
   current = states[current.next[input]]
   ```

На этом функция перехода закончилась.

---

Если при завершении входа текущее состояние будет конечным - значит автомат смог разобрать входную последовательность, если нет - нет.

---

Пример в сборке. По кнопке разбирает последовательность `a,b,a,b,a`

```js
var states = {
  p0: {
    name: 'p0',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
      'a': 'p1'
    }
  },

  p1: {
    name: 'p1',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
      'b': 'p2'
    }
  },

  p2: {
    name: 'p2',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
      'a': 'p3',
      'b': 'p4'
    }
  },

  p3: {
    name: 'p3',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
      'b': 'p5'
    }
  },

  p4: {
    name: 'p4',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
      'b': 'p4'
    }
  },
  p5: {
    name: 'p5',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
      'a': 'p3'
    }
  }
};
var current = states.p0;

function input(symbol) {
  if (!current.next[symbol]) throw Error('invalid input');

  current = states[current.next[symbol]];
  console.log(current);
}

function start() {
  current = states.p0;
  input('a');
  input('b');
  input('a');
  input('b');
  input('a');
  if (current.isFinish) {
    console.log('recognized')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Запустить конечный автомат" onclick="start()">
```

Answer (score 1):

По моему лучше сделать индикатор текущего состояния и три кнопки "a" "b" и "сброс".

Не совсем понятно зачем нужно поле isFinish.

```js
var currentState;
var p0 = {
    name: 'p0',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
        'a': 'p1'
    }
};

var p1 = {
    name: 'p1',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
        'b': 'p2'
    }
};

var p2 = {
    name: 'p2',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
        'a': 'p3',
        'b': 'p4'
    }
};

var p3 = {
    name: 'p3',
    isFinish: false,
    next: {
        'b': 'p5'
    }
};

var p4 ={
    name: 'p4',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
        'b': 'p4'
    }
};

var p5 = {
    name : 'p5',
    isFinish: true,
    next: {
        'a': 'p3'
    }
};
function reset() {
  currentState="p0";
  document.getElementById('currentState').innerHTML=eval(currentState+".name");
}
function mystep(e) {
  t=eval(currentState+".next."+e);
  if (t) {
    currentState=t;
    document.getElementById('currentState').innerHTML=eval(currentState+".name");
  }
}
reset(); //инициализация
```

```html
<div id="currentState"></div>
<br/>
<input type="button"  value="a" onclick="mystep('a');">
<input type="button"  value="b" onclick="mystep('b');">
<input type="button"  value="сброс" onclick="reset();">
<br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwSAe.png">
```

Comment: `isFinish` показывает конечное это состояние или нет. Но в коде значения этих флагов не соответствуют рисунку

Comment: @grundy, почему не соответствует?

Comment: @vita_run, потому что на картинке конечные состояния помечаются двойными кружками, то есть в данном случае это p1,p2,p3,p4

Comment: Я понял надо было ввод строкой делать. Ну ладно.